# How to send custom email with a file attachment in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, jakarta-mail, amazon-ses

I need to send a custom email with an Excel file attachment. I followed a guide I found online but keep getting this error: `javax.mail.internet.ParseException: Expected ';', got "charset"` at `message.writeTo(out)`.

I think it may have something to do with the way I am encoding the text. I'm not 100% sure if that part is written correctly.

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.util.Properties

import javax.activation.DataHandler
import javax.activation.FileDataSource
import javax.mail.Message
import javax.mail.Session
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart
import javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility

import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.RawMessage
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.SendRawEmailRequest
import java.io.File
import java.lang.System.out

.
.
.
.

fun sendEmail(){

        val file = File("test.xlsx")

        try{
            val defaultCharSet = MimeUtility.getDefaultJavaCharset()
            val session = Session.getDefaultInstance(Properties())
            val message = MimeMessage(session)
            message.setSubject(EMAIL_SUBJECT, "UTF-8")
            message.setFrom(InternetAddress(EMAIL_FROM))
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(EMAIL_TO))

            val msg_body =  MimeMultipart("alternative")
            val wrap =  MimeBodyPart()
            val textPart = MimeBodyPart()
            textPart.setContent(MimeUtility
                .encodeText(EMAIL_TEXT_BODY,defaultCharSet,"B"), "text/plain charset=UTF-8")
            textPart.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64")

            val htmlPart = MimeBodyPart()
            htmlPart.setContent(MimeUtility
                .encodeText(EMAIL_BODY_HTML,defaultCharSet,"B"),"text/html charset=UTF-8")
            htmlPart.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64")

            msg_body.addBodyPart(textPart)
            msg_body.addBodyPart(htmlPart)

            wrap.setContent(msg_body)

            val msg = MimeMultipart("mixed")
            message.setContent(msg)
            msg.addBodyPart(wrap)

            val att = MimeBodyPart()
            val fds = FileDataSource(file)
            att.dataHandler = DataHandler(fds)
            att.fileName = fds.name

            msg.addBodyPart(att)

            val client = AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build()

            message.writeTo(out)

            val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            message.writeTo(outputStream)
            val rawMessage = RawMessage(ByteBuffer.wrap(outputStream.toByteArray()))

            val rawEmailRequest = SendRawEmailRequest(rawMessage)
            client.sendRawEmail(rawEmailRequest)

            println("Email sent")

        }catch (e: Exception){
            println("Email failed to send with error: ${e.message}")
            println(e.printStackTrace())
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your MIME type syntax is wrong.  And your code is unnecessarily complex.
Try this:

```
        val textPart = MimeBodyPart()
        textPart.setText(EMAIL_TEXT_BODY, "utf-8")

        val htmlPart = MimeBodyPart()
        htmlPart.setText(EMAIL_BODY_HTML, "utf-8", "html")
```

And you don't need to encode the text or set the Content-Transfer-Encoding header, JavaMail will do all of that for you.